# Selenium with proxy settings throwing UnexpectedAlertPresentException

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm using Luminati proxy service with Selenium for scraping. I configured the proxy like this:

```
def get_driver(proxy_server):
    executable_path = os.path.join(app.config['JOBS_ROOT'], app.config['BROWSER_DRIVER'])
    firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    firefox_options = FirefoxOptions()
    firefox_options.add_argument('-headless')
    if proxy_server and proxy_server != LOCAL_HOST:
        firefox_profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
        firefox_profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http', 'zproxy.lum-superproxy.io')
        firefox_profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http_port', 22225)
        firefox_profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl', 'zproxy.lum-superproxy.io')
        firefox_profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl_port', 22225)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(
        executable_path=executable_path,
        firefox_options=firefox_options,
        firefox_profile=firefox_profile
    )
    return driver
```

Using Luminaty with such config requires authentication:

[image]

My first attempt to make sure the proxy IP was working is using https://whatsmyip.org:

```
driver.get('https://whatsmyip.org')
alert = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(expected_conditions.alert_is_present())
alert.send_keys(app.config['LUMINATI_CUSTOMER'] + Keys.TAB + app.config['LUMINATI_PASSWORD'])
alert.accept()
```

But, after accepting with `alert.accept()` the driver will just close not even displaying the contents of the page (plus, it seems very unstable, sometimes it works and sometimes not).

So I ended up repeating the `driver.get()` statement:

```
driver.get('https://whatsmyip.org')
alert = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(expected_conditions.alert_is_present())
alert.send_keys(app.config['LUMINATI_CUSTOMER'] + Keys.TAB + app.config['LUMINATI_PASSWORD'])
alert.accept()

driver.get('https://whatsmyip.org')
```

But I don't think that's how it is supposed to work.

More importantly, the majority of times I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cesar/Development/manar/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 812, in perform_job
    rv = job.perform()
  File "/home/cesar/Development/manar/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 588, in perform
    self._result = self._execute()
  File "/home/cesar/Development/manar/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 594, in _execute
    return self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "./jobs/scrapping.py", line 185, in scrap_plate_number
    record = scrap_and_recognize(driver, vehicle)
  File "./jobs/scrapping.py", line 91, in scrap_and_recognize
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "jcrm-botondetalle")]/a').click()
  File "/home/cesar/Development/manar/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/home/cesar/Development/manar/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/home/cesar/Development/manar/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/cesar/Development/manar/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 241, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
Message: Dismissed user prompt dialog: The proxy moz-proxy://zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225 is requesting a username and password. The site says: “Luminati”
```

I have no idea why Firefox is dismissing the alert. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```html
driver.get("https://<username>:<password>@www.example.com/index.html")
```